# Why is the following a cubical complex

Tags: simplicial-complex, topological-data-analysis

The german [Wikipedia-page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubischer_Komplex) on cubical complexes has the following example for a cubical complex.

I don't understand how the 45° rotated square on the right is the product of elementary intervals. As I understand it, the square would have to be aligned vertically/horizontally.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I can't read German, but usually how these complexes are embedded in some ambient space is not important.

Comment: The image description is just "example of a cubic complex". You can also switch wikipedia to english.
The definition says that the elements are cartesion products of intervals, so basically arbitrary hyper-cuboids if I understand correctly.
And the rotated square on the right doesn't fit that !?

Comment: As the others have said, if you redrew that complex with the square aligned vertically/horizontally, it would still represent the exact same cubical complex. In other words, how you draw the cubical complex does not matter --- all that matters is the combinatorics of which faces are connected to which faces. And in a cubical complex, each face has to be a product of elementary intervals --- a vertex, an edge, a square, a 3D cube, a 4D cube, etc, but the orientation with which you draw any such cube is not relevant for the data of a cubical complex.